# Android PendingIntent does not launch activity

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

I'm creating an application that use Google GCM Service.

So I defined this function:

```
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
```

onMessage calls a function, this is part of code:

```
 Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,ShowMess.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("id",current_id);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("cat", cat);
    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  //  notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT | PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

If I send a message to myself (with AsyncTask) but close fastly the applicaiton (Back Button) next messages will not launch activity (ShowMEss.class) Why in your opinion?

Bye

Thanks

Comment: PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, id, notificationIntent, 0); try with this code

Answer (score 0):

Your above code has not registered the notification. Are you missing following part in your code?

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = 
  (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I have omissed that part of code.. I Just update that